# Automating deja-dup with anacron: permissions problem?

Tags: permissions, mount, backup, deja-dup, anacron

I'm trying to get deja-dup automatically running via anacron, instead of via Unity, so that I have more control over job priorities.

In /etc/anacrontab, I'm hoping to use this row:

```
1       2       daily.backup    sudo -u username nice -n 19 ionice -c3 deja-dup --backup
```

This is failing. When I actually run the command at the command line myself without the sudo, i.e.

```
nice -n 19 ionice -c3 deja-dup --backup
```

... it works great. When I run it with the sudo, i.e.

```
sudo -u username nice -n 19 ionice -c3 deja-dup --backup
```

... I get a popup box saying "Backup location is not available. Waiting for [my external USB drive] to become connected..."

As far as I can tell, the drive is connected since backup works otherwise except via sudo -u (which I need for anacron). I've checked permissions on the mount directory, and they're all now owned by my username. Any suggestions on what I should be looking for?

Comment: how is the backup location referenced? sudo may need the absolute path instead of relative

Comment: In my Ubuntu settings, under Backups, I've got the storage location entered via the "Storage location" tab. The drive is references via a dropdown box (I've chosen the USB volume), and the directory listed there is simply the subdirectory of root where the backup goes (uncreatively called "backup"). Backup works great if I run it through Ubuntu settings. I just tried making that "/backup", but that didn't work when I tried running it from the command line.